# Is it good practice to trim whitespace (leading and trailing) when selecting/inserting/updating table field data?

Tags: sql-server, whitespace, trim

Presuming that the spaces are not important in a field's data, is it good practice to trim off the spaces when inserting, updating or selecting data from the table ?

I imagine different databases implement handling of spaces differently, so to avoid that headache, I'm thinking I should disallow leading and trailing spaces in any field data.

What do you think?

Comment: Since you mentioned designing a security framework; good call to prevent spaces at the ends of user names. This is a technique people could use pretend to be someone else. For example create a name "Liao ". Authentication sees this as different to "Liao", but when the names are displayed in a discussion board, other users would be unable to tell them apart. This is perhaps the simplest of spoofing techniques; you may want to investigate for a library to help with some of the trickier ones (e.g. replacing lower case L with 1, or in some fonts where lowercase RN looks like m).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the character-replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a good practice.  There are few things more soul crushing than spending an hour, a day, or any amount of time, chasing down a bug that ultimately was caused by a user typing an extra space.  That extra space can cause reports to go subtly wrong, or can cause an exception somewhere in your program, and unless you have put brackets around every print statement in your logs and error messages, you might not realize that it is there.  Even if you religiously trim spaces before using data you've pulled from the db, do future users of your data a favor and trim before putting it in.

Comment: Is there some "guaranteed" way to trim the spaces at the database - so that even if someone runs an insert from outside of my "code", say by running a direct SQL insert in the database IDE, the database can trim the whitespace. A trigger perhaps is possible?

Comment: Eh, sometimes whitespace is significant.

Answer (score 4):

If leading and trailing spaces are unimportant, then I'd trim them off before inserting or updating. There should then be no unnecessary spaces on a select.

This brings some advantages. Less space required in a row means that potentially more rows can exist in a data page which leads to faster data retrieval (less to retrieve). Also, you are not constantly trimming data on SELECTs. (Uses the DRY [don't repeat yourself] principle here)

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's a good practice in most scenarios. If you can confidently say that data is worthless, and the cost of removing it is minimal, then remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I would trim them (unless you are actually using the whitespace data), simply because it is easy to do, and spaces are particularly hard to spot if they do cause problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For typical data enty it's not worth the overhead.  Is there some reason you think you are going to get lots of extra blank lines?  If you are then it might be a good idea to trim to keep DB size down but otherwise no.

Comment: One reason I want to trim: When creating a user account (and other "objects"), I don't want a user indaverdently typing in a trailing space, and then not being able to login. Apart from being a "annoyance" (if you can call it that), it would generate unnecessary customer support calls. I want to apply this "theory" to all "objects" that have a "name" (virtuall all objects have a name) in a software I'm developing.

Comment: Correction to comment : user would type "john" but while creating the user account, he had accidentally typed in "john ". Of course, I could warn at time of user account creation, but this is something easy for John to forget since the whitespace isn't a "visible" character.

Comment: You stated in your first sentence "Presuming that the spaces are not important in a field's data...".  If the field is something that is going to be used for user authentication then quite clearly the spaces ARE important in the fields data.  Your comment suggests an entirely different scenario than your question does.

Further generally username fields usually follow validation rules which go way beyond simple trimming.

Comment: @Dennis - i'm designing my own security framework, and the usernames will come directly from a user, not from any other source; so i get to control this aspect with regard to user names; and yes, there will be other checks for the contents of the username.

Comment: @Dennis - the spaces are important for passwords i suppose, but not for usernames imo

Answer (score 0):

Trailing spaces are particularly problematic, specifically in regards ANSI_NULLS behaviour.

For instance, colname = '1' can return true where colname like '1' returns false

Thus, given trailing spaces in varchar columns are ambiguous, truncation is most likely preferable, particularly because there is no real information in such data and it creates ambiguity in the behaviour of SQL Server.

For example, look at the discussion at this question:

[Why would SqlServer select statement select rows which match and rows which match and have trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143313/why-would-sqlserver-select-statement-select-rows-which-match-and-rows-which-match/1143324#1143324)

Answer (score 0):

Handling trailing spaces is a good practise. It is a common mistake in databases and it leads to long searching of mistakes.

Either trim them during insert/ update, or add a check clause to your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tblData
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_Spaces_tblData 
CHECK 
(
    datalength(USERID)>(0) 
    AND datalength(ltrim(rtrim(USERID)))=datalength(USERID) 
)
```

In this case, users get an error when they try to insert or update.

This has the advantage, that users **know** about the mistake. Very often, they already have trailing spaces in some Excel sheet, and then they copy-paste. So it's good for them to know about this, so they can remove the error also in their excel sheets.