# Why is there is a difference between equality comparison between equal operator and like operator?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname  
FROM authors
WHERE au_lname = 'Green '
```

```
au_lname                                 au_fname
---------------------------------------- --------------------
Green                                    Marjorie
```

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE au_lname LIKE 'Green '
```

```
au_lname                                 au_fname
---------------------------------------- --------------------
```

Could anyone please explain me why is the second query is not returning the expected row?

Answer (score 4):

It's a quirk of the standards apparently. Might as well be explicit:

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92
>   specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI standard requires
>   padding for the character strings used
>   in comparisons so that their lengths
>   match before comparing them. The
>   padding directly affects the semantics
>   of WHERE and HAVING clause predicates
>   and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, **Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent** for most comparison
>   operations.
>
> **The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate**. When the right side of
>   a LIKE predicate expression features a
>   value with a trailing space, SQL
>   Server does not pad the two values to
>   the same length before the comparison
>   occurs. Because the purpose of the
>   LIKE predicate, by definition, is to
>   facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests,
>   this does not violate the section of
>   the ANSI SQL-92 specification
>   mentioned earlier.

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626), [here](http://richarddingwall.name/2007/12/28/t-sql-equality-operator-ignores-trailing-spaces/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space).

Bizarre - given the terms "equal" and "like" I would have expected the latter to be the more liberal.

Comment: @Mark Byers - Didn't mean to come off negatively (perhaps my response was tainted by the other) just didn't get a "why" from your answer and I personally wanted to know why myself.

Answer (score 1):

your char(8) literal 'Green ' value is automatically converted to the same data type as `au_lname` column, which is most likely varchar(), so the trailing space is removed in the conversion.  This is probabily the optimizer at work trying to make the data types the same, so an index can be used.

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname  
FROM authors
WHERE au_lname = 'Green ' --auto conversion to varchar() is 'Green'
```

using LIKE, there is no auto conversion from the CHAR(8) 'Green ' value, so no matches are found.  Most likely, this is done, so the pattern matching capabilities are preserved.  if you want to search for `LIKE 'xyz% '` that is quite different than `LIKE 'xyz%'`

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE au_lname LIKE 'Green ' --no conversion, remains CHAR(8) 'Green '
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the padding stored.

`LIKE 'Green%'` and `= 'Green'` will both find 'Green' whereas `LIKE 'Green '` will not find 'Green' but `LIKE 'Green%'` will.  And '%Green%' will find ' Green ', 'Mr. Green', '  Green', 'Green  ', ' Green Ghost' and 'Greentree'

NOTE: most sql will actually match the case on - as well as in: 'GreeN', 'green' 'GREEN' all match ='Green'.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - this adds value to the question and body of answers IMHO which is in the standard of the site.