# Linq Empty String vs. Space

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query

```
var x = c from context.customers
where c.Name == ''
```

and

```
var x =  c from context.customers
where c.Name == ' '
```

I have a customername column in SQL 2008 database, with varchar(50) and one customer is blank and other has a space, but the TSQL generated by Linq is right but return for both queries return both customers and not 1 record which I want, which is either blank or has a whitespace. I know the underlying problem is a SQL server issue as per this question asked.

[SQL Server 2008 Empty String Vs Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space)

I want to modify my Linq query. how can I do this? without using SQL server T-SQL commands in linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework then make use of [SqlFunctions.DataLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487157.aspx) to distinguish between an empty string and white-space.

e.g

```
var x = c from context.customers
where c.Name == '' && SqlFunctions.DataLength(c.Name) == 0
```

and

```
var x = c from context.customers
where c.Name == '' && SqlFunctions.DataLength(c.Name) != 0
```

SqlFunctions.DataLength translates to the TSQL [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function.
DATALENGTH will give you the number of bytes a string requires including any white-space.  By comparison the LEN function will give you the number of characters after trimming any trailing white-space.