# Sorting varying sizes of blank strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

In one of my queries, I was trying to sort by a column that had a `varchar` data type.
I wanted to show columns that had a space after the columns that had empty strings, but the output of `ORDER BY` did not work as I expected it to (in fact it surprised me).

Here is a [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5b924/1) that shows the problem.

I have researched this issue and the only partially relevant article I found is [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cf874246-b8d8-4d76-ae36-e6a13ebfe0a7/ascii-isnull-char-and-empty-string-puzzle).

What I want to know is why would SQL Server do this, and what can I do to force the sorting to consider these values as different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GoatCO Thanks, I have been searching for an explanation for hours and could not find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate in the `ORDER BY` by replacing a space with something:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab 
ORDER BY LEN(REPLACE(val,' ','X'));
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5b924/6/0)

As for why SQL Server behaves this way I can't shed any light.

Comment: I was more interested in knowing why this was happening? If it was just about sorting, I could have replaced the space with a character and achieved that. Also my column has values too, it saves user names.

Comment: @user2989408 The 'why' seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space
If you need help in getting sorting to go a certain way then post some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DATALENGTH()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function

```
SELECT *
FROM Tab
ORDER BY DATALENGTH(val)
```

Comment: +1 Hadn't come across that function before.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5b924/9/0

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me, as my column has other values too.

Comment: Can you `ORDER BY val, DATALENGTH(val)` ?

Comment: @Anon +1 Yes that would work. Although, I was looking to get an answer that kind of explained why this was happening, and it seems that the reason is explained in the post mentioned by Goat CO?