# How does SQL Server 2008R2 handle Spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just realised, the following behaviour of SQL Server

```
SELECT
    1
WHERE
    ' ' = '        '
```

Seemingly the string with just 1 space equals the string with 8 spaces. Can anyone explain, why that is and how i can compare empty strings?

Comment: Try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space

Comment: Voting to close - yes, essentially same question and the answer answers this perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, , General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations

use DataLength to compare in where clause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms173486.aspx

Answer (score -1):

To compare for empty string

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(columnName))=''
```

Comment: @downvoter plz explain wrong approach and what should be better way..

Comment: did you try what you posted? have a table with a varchar column and insert `SELECT '  '  UNION ALL SELECT ' ' UNION ALL SELECT ''` your select will still get all those three values back