# ODBC: How to bind a empty string?

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

I have a code that binds a string to an ODBC statement that looks like this

```
std::string v = "...";
SQLBindParameter(stmt, c, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR,
                          v.size(), 0, &v[0], v.size(), 0)
```

It works for any regular string, but not for empty string. I get an error message instead:

> Error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value

I changed the function call to this

```
 SQLBindParameter(stmt, c, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR,
                              std::max<SQLUINTEGER>(v.size(), 1), 0, &v[0], v.size(), 0)
```

And now empty string can be inserted, yet it is converted into a space instead of an empty string.

I don't want to insert a NULL value because many SQL statements become counter-intuitive when NULL is encountered. Is any way to bind an empty string at all?

(The database engine is SQL Server 2005 with ODBC3)

Comment: Aren't empty strings and strings with one space treated the same in CHAR fields in most DBs including SQLServer (e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space). So isn't your modified call actually working correctly in the same way as someone else reported solving this problem at http://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/odbc-sqlbindparameter-hy104-howto-bind-an-empty-string-to-an-sql_varchar/

Comment: @mc110: I did chose his route, but I thought it was only a hack. Apparent SQL standard specifies that trailing spaces be ignored. It is so unfortunate. You should turn that into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty strings and strings with one space are treated the same in CHAR fields in most DBs, including SQLServer (e.g. see [SQL Server 2008 Empty String vs. Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space) and a MicroSoft explanation that this is part of the SQL-92 spec here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626).

So your modified call actually works correctly.

This is the same way someone else reported solving this problem at http://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/odbc-sqlbindparameter-hy104-howto-bind-an-empty-string-to-an-sql_varchar/

> So to allow the empty (zero length) C string to be bound, we need to
>   simply bind it to a parameter of at lease size 1.