# SQL Server 2012 blank string comparison with 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, behavior

I am running this query on SQL Server 2012:

```
select 'weird' 
where '' = 0
```

It's returning `'weird'`.

As far as I understand, `''` is quite different from `0`. So please explain why the above happens.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Empty String vs. Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, taking a look at the data types where they stand in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(0, 'BaseType'),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('', 'BaseType')
```

They return `int, varchar` respectively.

When comparing two different data types, the data type with the lower precedence will convert to the higher precedence, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

In this case, `Varchar` converts to `int`.

```
select cast('' AS int)
```

The above returns `0`.

Thus

```
select 'weird' where 0 = 0
```