# Are white space strings the same as empty strings in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, string

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  Previously, I thought empty strings (i.e., '') were different than strings of just white space characters (e.g., '   ').  Also, I thought that white space strings of different lengths were different from each other (e.g., ' ' vs. '   ').  However, it seems that SQL treats all of these the same.  That is, empty strings are the same as white space strings of any length.  Is this expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Empty String vs. Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not white space in the conventional sense of any invisible character that affects spacing (such as tab, newline, etc) - it's only the literal space character (ASCII 32)

And it's standard SQL - if two strings are of unequal length, the shorter string is padded with spaces before comparisons occur.