# !IsNullOrEmpty equivalent in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating an SSRS report and during writing the query I look up the code logic for the data that needs to be retrieved in query. There is lots of usage of !String.IsNullOrEmpty method so I want to know what is the shortest and best way to do the equivalent check in SQL server?

```
WHERE t.Name IS NOT NULL OR T.Name != ''
```

or....

```
WHERE LEN(t.Name) > 0
```

which one is correct? Or is there any other alternative?

Comment: `WHERE ISNULL(T.Name, '') != ''`

Comment: both (plus @DenisRubashkin one) should be working

Comment: Just realize trailing spaces are ignored in SQL. So `' ' = ''` evaluates to true.

Comment: @HoneyBadger interresting behaviour

Comment: @HoneyBadger see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space)

Comment: Definitely avoid applying functions to your column. Also `T.Name <> ''` is the only thing you need in SQL Server, a `NULL` value will result to unknown and be treated as false implicitly. Read Roger's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the desired result is the simplest possible one-liner then:

```
WHERE  NULLIF(Name, '') IS NOT NULL
```

However, from a performance point of view following alternative is SARGable, therefore indexes potentially can be used to spot and filter out records with such values

```
WHERE  Name IS NOT NULL  AND Name != ''
```

An example:

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT 1 AS ID, '' AS Name UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, '  ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, NULL UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 'abc' 
)


SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE  Name IS NOT NULL  AND Name != ''
```

Results to:

```
ID  Name
---------
4   abc
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in equivalent of `IsNullOrEmpty()` in T-SQL, largely due to the fact that trailing blanks are ignored when comparing strings. One of your options:

```
where len(t.Name) > 0
```

would be enough as `len()` ignores trailing spaces too. Unfortunately it can make the expression non-SARGable, and any index on the `Name` column might not be used. However, this one should do the trick:

```
where t.Name > ''
```

P.S. For the sake of completeness, the `datalength()` function takes all characters into account; keep in mind however that it returns the number of **bytes**, not characters, so for any `nvarchar` value the result will be at least double of what you might expect (and with supplementary characters / surrogate pairs the number should be even higher, if my memory serves).

Comment: For the SARGable note, +1. Most people don't realize how important that is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use WHERE LEN(t.Name)>0.
You can also verify as below:

-- Count the Total number of records

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblName as t

-- Count the Total number of 'NULL' or 'Blank' records

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblName as t WHERE ISNULL(t.Name,'')= ''

-- Count the Total number of 'NOT NULL' records

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblName as t WHERE LEN(t.Name)>0

Thanks.