# How does LIKE keyword deal with trailing spaces in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, varchar

Could someone please explain me why does following query output '1'?

```
IF 'SQL ' LIKE 'SQL '       
    SELECT '1'
ELSE                        
    SELECT '0'
```

Output:

```
    1
```

Based on the clarification made in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space), I came to know, when we use `LIKE` with `VARCHAR` datatypes, it treats trailing whitespace as significant in the pattern (RHS) but not the match expression (LHS).

So, based on the above logic, in the above query, match expression `'SQL '` (LHS) is to be treated as `'SQL'` and then to be matched with pattern `'SQL '` (RHS) and should be resulting 0. But we are getting '1' instead of '0'.

But for the below cases, we are getting expected results.

```
IF 'SQL' LIKE 'SQL '        
    SELECT '1'
ELSE                        
    SELECT '0'
    
IF 'SQL ' LIKE 'SQL'        
    SELECT '1'
ELSE                        
    SELECT '0'
```

Output:

```
    0
    1
```

Comment: I think you've got muddled with your example: the "unexpected" case at the top of the question is exactly the same as the second "expected" case at the end of it.

Comment: The left side is trimmed as the specification says, in normal cases the right space will be trimmed when you insert it.

Comment: You could take some uncertainty out of the experiment by explicitly defining datatypes. What you have there is not really a practical case.

Answer (score 1):

"Insignificant" is not the same as "removed"; it means something more like "not required". A different way of stating the rule would be this:

> If the pattern includes a trailing space, then that space is *required* to exist in the string being matched (the space is a "significant" part of the pattern); but if the *string being matched* includes a trailing space, that space is *not required* to exist in the pattern (the space is not a "significant" part of the string).

Put this way, the example makes perfect sense - the pattern has a "significant" space, so that space is *required* in the string being matched; the string does indeed have that space, so the match succeeds.

On the other hand, when the string on the left hand side has an "insignificant" space, it is *not required* for that space to also appear in the pattern; so patterns with *or* without that space will match the string.

Comment: **_if no. of Trailing spaces in Expression (LHS) >= no. of Trailing spaces in Pattern (RHS), Then Match occurs_**, _Assuming others characters are same._   After analyzing all of yours comments and provided link, Above is the my takeaway.  Thank You all.

Comment: @abhishek Yes, I think that's a reasonable way of putting it. Glad I could help.