# Sql Where Clause not working if add space at the end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sql Query

```
Select * from usertable where username = 'xyz (space)';
```

It is giving me the result which is wrong the result has to come only when i not add space at end because in database there is no space.

Is there any function or how can i do that.

Comment: you running query from php

Comment: no it is in sql server 2008

Comment: @Sharmaji use Trim

Comment: Please give me sample query actualy i don't want the result if there is space at end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Empty String vs. Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space)

Comment: There are several duplicates here on SO regarding this phenomenon: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938566/how-can-i-make-sql-server-return-false-for-comparing-varchars-with-and-without-t), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143313/why-would-sqlserver-select-statement-select-rows-which-match-and-rows-which-match), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is CHAR data with trailing spaces you could use the [RTRIM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178660.aspx) function like this;

```
select * from usertable where RTRIM(username) = 'xyz'
```

EDIT: In order to match including trailing spaces you can use the [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function, like this;

```
select * from usertable where username = 'xyz ' AND
                              DATALENGTH(username) = DATALENGTH('xyz ')
```

Comment: data is varchar and rtrim will remove space from database but what i want is if there is space at end then result will not come.

Comment: ..thanks its working but change query like below:
select * from usertable where username = 'xyz ' AND
                              DATALENGTH(username ) = DATALENGTH('xyz ')

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to filter the records those have the space in the last position.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Data VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (Data) VALUES ('xyz'), ('Sharma ');

SELECT * FROM @TestTable WHERE Data = 'Sharma ';
SELECT * FROM @TestTable WHERE Data = 'Sharma';
```

you will get the same result for `WHERE Data = 'Sharma ' and 'Sharma'`

Using `SUBSTRING(Data, DATALENGTH(Data), 1)` you can get the last character of the column and add the condition in WHERE clause will solve your problem:

```
DECLARE @TestingValue AS VARCHAR(20) = 'Sharma'; -- 'xyz' -- 'Sharma '

SELECT * FROM @TestTable WHERE Data = @TestingValue AND SUBSTRING(@TestingValue, DATALENGTH(@TestingValue), 1) = ' ' ;
```

The above block return result if you set `'Sharma '` as parameter value.

Comment: Actualy i dn't want result if there is space enter by user

Answer (score 1):

This is because [SQL Server follows ANSI 92 rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626) which stipulates that:

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, <Comparison Predicate>, General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. **The ANSI standard requires padding for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them**. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.

*(my emphasis)*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the result if there is space at end you can use below query

```
select * from usertable where username not like '% '
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this one:

```
    select * from usertable where right(username,1) <> ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code works for me........

```
select * from usertable where username = 'xyz (Space) ' AND
                              DATALENGTH(username) = DATALENGTH('xyz (Space) ')
```